# Custom id AutoField in Django model

Tags: python, django

i want create a custom field with  AutoField
description:
Code generated by the system is increasing gradually, the code consists of 5 digits, there are no 2 identical codes. For example: 00001, 00002

this is my code :

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, max_length=5, blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, validators=[len_phone])
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: `AutoField` creates an integer sequence. With how many leading zeros you format the integer for output is unrelated to the field itself.

Comment: but My teacher wants not to enter the code but still generates the code 00001.

Comment: You are confusing data (integer) and its representation (string). To create a sequence you will have to use an integer anyway. And `int()` is fine with leading zeros.

Comment: then I will use char but how do I get it to increment. for example: 00001 -> 00002

Comment: You don't. You increment integers, not characters. So, use an int!